# How to overwrite a text file in spark scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, overwrite

Need to overwrite a text file from a dataframe with 4 columns in scala spark

I tried the below command

```
result.rdd.map(x =\> x.mkString(“\\t”)).saveAsTextFile("/user/Output")
```

It's working

I want to overwrite the file next time

And also specify where do i  need to mention repartition parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrameWriter` has method `mode` to specify a saveMode which can set to `overwrite` and method `partitionBy` to partition data by key in your parameter.example code:

```scala
df.write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .partitionBy("partition_key")
  .save("/path/to/table")
```